# null checked in .equals() method

Tags: java, null, equals

I'm not sure why a null checker in my .equals() method isn't working. It is set up as the following:

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
if (other == null)
    return false
else
    return (this.param == other.param...)
```

I tried making two objects, 1 with parameters and 1 null and tried the equals method and got the null pointer error. What's wrong?

Comment: fix the syntax errors first

Comment: Which line throws the error, minimal working full code please, with error copy. Maybe other isn't null, but other.param is, or param. Read the error message carefully. They look often annoying, so much boilerplate!, but you have to analyze them carefully. You'll get faster doing it, over time.

Comment: what does `other.param...` mean? Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Kindly post your complete code

Answer (score -1):

Try doing something like this:
https://www.webucator.com/how-to/how-compare-two-objects-with-the-equals-method-java.cfm

Here it should not matter if you check for a null object since that is just a different instance of an object.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.